# Visual Studio CodeLens with Mercurial

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial, visual-studio-2015

В VS 2015 Enterprise есть интеграция с git. Студия (CodeLens) показывает над методом когда и кем он правился. Вопрос вот в чём: поддерживает ли какой либо плагин для mercurial такую же функциональность? Если ли смысл ставить VisualHG?